# change OBJECTPROPERTY IsEncrypted to false with tsql script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database with some encrypted views which I would like to export but I have to change the encryption from true to false. The following code shows the encrypted objects and I was wondering if it's possible with a simple modification to the code to change the encryption from true to false.

```
USE Tfs_Database
GO
SELECT name, object_id, type_desc
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, N'IsEncrypted') = 1
ORDER BY type_desc, name;
GO
```

I need this in order to use the auto generate scripts feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change system tables. And what would be the point? You would change that bit column to 0 but the object is still encrypted. So what use would you have for the unintelligible scripts you would produce?

The right way to script encrypted objects is to pull them from source control. After all, if you're encrypting objects, you'd better have them in source control.

If you can't do that, then search around the web for a function to decrypt stored procedures. It's not exactly NSA material.

Comment: I was thinking that in the process of changing the 1 to 0 it would try to replicate the change onto the data, meaning it would decrypt it. I'm sad to see that it doesn't.

Comment: @primero no - you can't change that value, and even if you could, it wouldn't magically go out and decrypt, it would just change the value. If you're encrypting these views, why can't you pull them from source control? Surely you're not encrypting them and not saving the original definition anywhere?